# Python: using Selenium for multiple URLs without quitting driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium to scrape a number of URLs.
Here is part of the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'first URL'
driver.execute_script('''window.open("'''+str(url)+'''","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(3)
doc1 = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

url = 'second URL'
driver.execute_script('''window.open("'''+str(url)+'''","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(3)
doc2 = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

But what I see is that doc1 and doc2 are the same.
Any idea why this happens?

I guess one way is to do `driver.quit()` after getting `doc1` and then do everything again for `second URL`. But I don't want to quit the chrome. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "**`driver.get("url")`**" 
in place of `driver.execute_script('''window.open("'''+str(url)+'''","_blank");''')`

Answer (score 1):

In your first `driver.execute_script()`, it will launch the browser with default window and then it will navigate to the provided URL in another window so you will have total of 2 windows and you are doing `driver.switch_to_window()` to switch to the second window and this is fine.

When it comes to the second `driver.execute_script()`, you will have two previous windows along with the new one so total 3 windows you will have. If you do the `driver.window_handles[1]` again then you will get the same page source so to avoid this, you need to change an index number to 2.

Try the below code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'first URL'
driver.execute_script('''window.open("'''+str(url)+'''","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(3)
doc1 = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

url = 'second URL'
driver.execute_script('''window.open("'''+str(url)+'''","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[2])
time.sleep(3)
doc2 = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

To learn more about working with JavaScriptExecutor then refer [This Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UghwIKHB8Wo&list=PLzIX4GKTh5quMkUB32JKpknaHzTnaAFOe)

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct too. The first answer was simpler and earier so I accepted that.

Comment: Yes, if you use `driver.get()` then no need to do any switching between windows but since you are using `JavaScriptExecutor`, I have proposed solution in your way and there just you need to change an index number...

Comment: You are welcome and no problem... Just tried explaining what's wrong in your code... Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

If you place all URLs in a list or tuple (e.g., "myURLs"), you could use the following approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
myURLs = ["https://google.com", "https://bing.com", "https://duckduckgo.com"]
driver = [None] * len(myURLs)
# for info on enumerate(), see link below
for i, item in enumerate(myURLs):
    driver[i] = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver[i].get(item)
```

[7 PEP 279: enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html)